# passing values in asp.net with 2 forms

Tags: asp.net

i have 2 webpages Default.aspx and Default2.aspx,

once the user enters the data in Default.aspx ,

Default.aspx redirects the user to  Default2.aspx with Request.QueryString,

for some reason im getting

txtUserId.Text does not exists in the current context  Default.aspx.cs

Default.aspx:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>QueryString Example in asp.net</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div><b>QueryString Example</b></div><br />
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td><b>UserId:</b></td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txtUserId" runat="server"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>UserName:</b></td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><asp:Button ID="btnSend" Text="Send Values" runat="server" onclick="btnSend_Click"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm3 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx?UserId=" + txtUserId.Text + "&UserName=" + txtUserName.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Default2.aspx:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>QueryString Example in asp.net</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div><b>QueryString parameter Values in Default2.aspx Page</b></div><br />
<div><b>UserId:</b><asp:Label ID="lblUserId" runat="server"/></div><br />
<div><b>UserName:</b><asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server"/></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default2.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm4 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                lblUserId.Text = Request.QueryString["UserId"];
                lblUserName.Text = Request.QueryString["UserName"];
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the `<%@ Page` directive in your .aspx files? If so, please include them in your question. If not, please state that.

Comment: Can you get `txtUserName.Text` ?

Comment: nope both values are not accessible, i wonder if that has to do because the file is using xhtml format ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your .aspx file code behind is match with your page like this:

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="yournamespace.WebForm2"  .... %>
```

and your code behind class should match the CodeBehind property:

```
public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    ...
```

In the above example `CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs"` is pointing to `class WebForm2`

Comment: i have tried to add this  line   <%@ Page Language="C#" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="AssessorsLounge.WebForm2"  .... %>but all im getting now is

Comment: The `Inherits` value is just an example for you, it needs to be replaced with your current namespace.